# Como inserir e removendo dados de tabela com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O Código abaixo não responde corretamente, as vezes coloca duas virgulas, as vezes só remove as virgulas e as vezes dá certo. ex quando clico em delete fica assim no input: [dado1,dado2dado3].

```js
 function grava(id) {
      var vara = document.getElementById("id-select").value;
      vara = vara.replace(',,', ',');
    
      if (vara.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("inter").value = id.value + ",";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("inter").value = vara + id.value + ",";
    
      }
      var valor = id.value;
      var markup = "<tr id='" +
        valor.trim() +
        "'  >" +
    
        "<td style='border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228); cursor: pointer; color: #000; text-align: center;'>" +
        valor.trim() +
        " </td>" +
        "<td style='border: 1px solid rgb(228, 228, 228); cursor: pointer; color: #000; text-align: center;'>" +
        "<button type='button' id='delete-row' title='Excluir' onClick='deleteRow(this,\"" +
        valor.trim() +
        "\")'   class='btn btn-danger delete'> <i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>" +
        "</td>" + "</tr>";
      $("#tbOptions tbody").append(markup);
    
    }
    
    function deleteRow(btn, item) {
      var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
      row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    
      var vara = document.getElementById("inter").value;
      vara = vara.replace(',,', ',');
      var array = vara.split(',');
      var operadores = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var id = array[i].trim().replace(' ', '').toLowerCase();
        var comp = item.trim().replace(' ', '').toLowerCase();
        if (id != comp && id.length > 0) {
          operadores += array[i].trim() + ",";
        }
      }
      operadores = operadores.substring(0, operadores.length - 1);
      document.getElementById("inter").value = operadores;
    
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    
      <select id="id-select" onchange="grava(this)">
        <option value="opcao1">opcao1</option>
        <option value="opcao2">opcao2</option>
        <option value="opcao3">opcao3</option>
        <option value="opcao4">opcao4</option>
        <option value="opcao5">opcao5</option>
    
      </select>
    </form>
    
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="tbOptions">
      <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);">
          <th style="cursor: pointer; color: #000; text-align: center;"> Opções Selecionadas</th>
          <th style="cursor: pointer; color: #000; text-align: center;"> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>


<input type="text" id="inter">
```

E consigo inserir a mesma opção duas vezes.
O que há de errado?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai uma alternativa:

```js
function grava() {

  //pega o valor da select
  var getValue = $('#id-select').val();

  //adiciona a linha da tabela
  var incremment = "<tr id='" + getValue + "'><td>" + getValue + "<button onclick='exclui(this)' id='e_" + getValue + "'>Excluir</button></td></tr>";

  //verifica se a opção ja foi adicionada
  if ($('table').find('tr[id="' + getValue + '"]').length) {
    alert('Elemento já adicionado!');
  } else {
    $('table>tbody').append(incremment);
    var valoratual = $('#inter').val();
    if (valoratual == "") {
      $('#inter').val(getValue);
    } else {
      $('#inter').val(valoratual + ', ' + getValue);
    }
  }
}

function exclui(idObj) {

  var myId = document.getElementById(idObj.id);
  
  var myInter = $('#inter').val();
  var trId = $(myId).parents('tr').attr('id');
  var replaceId = myInter.replace(trId,'');
  
  $('#inter').val(replaceId);
  $(myId).parents('tr').remove();
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="POST">
  <select id="id-select" onchange="grava()">

    <option value="opcao1" name="1">opcao1</option>
    <option value="opcao2" name="2">opcao2</option>
    <option value="opcao3" name="3">opcao3</option>
    <option value="opcao4" name="4">opcao4</option>
    <option value="opcao5" name="5">opcao5</option>

  </select>
</form>

<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="tbOptions">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);">
      <th style="cursor: pointer; color: #000; text-align: center;"> Opções Selecionadas</th>
      <th style="cursor: pointer; color: #000; text-align: center;"> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

  </tbody>

  <input type="text" id="inter" />
```

Comment: Legal, muito obrigado. Como eu faço o "verifica se a opção já foi adicionada" no meu código?

Comment: No meu exemplo eu atribuo um id ao tr, correspondente ao nome da opção selecionada. Após isso eu só verifico se ela existe ou não.